# Building N-th order Markovian transition matrix from a given sequence

Tags: python, numpy, probability, markov-chains

I am trying to create a function which can transform a given input sequence to a transition matrix of the requested order. I found an implementation for the first-order Markovian transition matrix.

Now, I want to be able to come up with a solution which can calculate 2nd and 3rd order transition matrices.

Example of the 1st order matrix implementation:

```py
import numpy as np

# sequence with 3 states -> 0, 1, 2

a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2]


def transition_matrix_first_order(seq):
    M = np.full((3, 3), fill_value = 1/3, dtype= np.float64)
    for (i,j) in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
        M[i, j] += 1

    M = M / M.sum(axis = 1, keepdims = True)

    return M

print(transition_matrix_first_order(a))
```

Which gives me this:

```
[[0.61111111 0.19444444 0.19444444]
 [0.38888889 0.38888889 0.22222222]
 [0.22222222 0.22222222 0.55555556]]
```

When making a 2nd order matrix, it should have `unique_state_count ** order` rows and `unique_state_count` columns. In the example above, I have 3 unique states, so the matrix will have 9x3 structure.
Desirable function sample:
`cal_tr_matrix(seq, unique_state_count, order)`

Comment: Well you should simply take the last previous indices into account when you increment the matrix. I would furthermore remove the `M = M/M.sum(..)` out of the `for` loop, since this does not look correct.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it. I made a mistake when copy-pasting from the notebook :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding about the Markov chains and their transition matrices.

First of all, the estimated transition matrix your function produces is unfortunately not correct. Why? Let's refresh.

A discrete Markov chain in discrete time with `N` different states has a transition matrix `P` of size `N x N`, where a (i, j) element is `P(X_1=j|X_0=i)`, i.e. the probability of transition from state `i` to state `j` in a single time step.

Now a transition matrix of order `n`, denoted `P^{n}`is once again a matrix of size `N x N` where a (i, j) element is `P(X_n=j|X_0=i)`, i.e. the probability of transition from state `i` to state `j` in `n` time steps.

A wonderful result says: `P^{n} = P^n`, i.e. taking `n` powers of single-step transition matrix gives you the `n`-step transition matrix.

Now with this recap, all that is needed is to estimate `P` from the given sequence, then to estimate `P^{n}` one can just use the already estimated `P` and take a `n`-th power of the matrix. So how to estimate the matrix `P`? Well if we denote `N_{ij}` the number of observations of transition from state `i` to state `j` and `N_{i*}` the number of observations being in state `i`, then `P_{ij} = N_{ij} / N_{i*}`.

Overall here in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def transition_matrix(arr, n=1):
    """"
    Computes the transition matrix from Markov chain sequence of order `n`.

    :param arr: Discrete Markov chain state sequence in discrete time with states in 0, ..., N
    :param n: Transition order
    """

    M = np.zeros(shape=(max(arr) + 1, max(arr) + 1))
    for (i, j) in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
        M[i, j] += 1

    T = (M.T / M.sum(axis=1)).T

    return np.linalg.matrix_power(T, n)

transition_matrix(arr=a, n=1)

>>> array([[0.63636364, 0.18181818, 0.18181818],
>>>       [0.4       , 0.4       , 0.2       ],
>>>       [0.2       , 0.2       , 0.6       ]])

transition_matrix(arr=a, n=2)

>>> array([[0.51404959, 0.22479339, 0.26115702],
>>>       [0.45454545, 0.27272727, 0.27272727],
>>>       [0.32727273, 0.23636364, 0.43636364]])

transition_matrix(arr=a, n=3)

>>> array([[0.46927122, 0.23561232, 0.29511645],
>>>       [0.45289256, 0.24628099, 0.30082645],
>>>       [0.39008264, 0.24132231, 0.36859504]])
```

Interesting thing, when you set the order `n` to a fairly high number, the higher and higher powers of the `P` matrix seem to converge to some very specific values. That's known as stationary/invariant distribution of the Markov chain and it gives a very good indication of how the chain behaves over a long period of time/transitions. Also:

```
P = transition_matrix(a, 1)
P111 = transition_matrix(a, 111)
print(P)
print(P111.dot(P))
```

EDIT: Now to the tweaked solution based on your comment, I'd suggest to have higher dimensional matrices for higher orders instead of exploding the number of rows. One way would be like this:

```
def cal_tr_matrix(arr, order):

    _shape = (max(arr) + 1,) * (order + 1)
    M = np.zeros(_shape)

    for _ind in zip(*[arr[_x:] for _x in range(order + 1)]):
        M[_ind] += 1
    return M

res1 = cal_tr_matrix(a, 1)
res2 = cal_tr_matrix(a, 2)
```

Now the element `res1[i, j]` says how many times transition i->j happened, while the element `res2[i, j, k]` says how many times transition i->j->k happened.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for the input. By first order transition matrix I mean how many times state i is followed by j. In my example, I am building a 3x3 matrix which shows how many times state 0 is followed by state 0 and etc. What I mean by the second order matrix is that, now i want to know how many times 0 - 0 is followed by 0 , 0 -0 is followed by 1 .... 2-1 is followed by 0 and etc. 
My rows will be permutations of length 2 of this sequence and columns will be the states themselves. Maybe I used different notations in my questions, I am not mathematician by profession